# How to handle Form.MaximumBox click

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, forms

everyone!
I need to track event when user is clicking maximumBox in window.
It is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this : Make use of WindowState property

```
   private void  Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
       {
           \\ code to execute after Maximize button has been clicked
           MessageBox.Show(this.WindowState.ToString());

       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the form's window state in the resize event.

```
   private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)

   {



       if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)

       {

           \\ code to execute after Maximize button has been clicked

       }



       if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)

       {

           \\ code to execute after Minimize button has been clicked

       }



   }
```